# Webpack - export window.function failing

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am a total newbie in Webpack which I have started to use **3 days** ago to change how we load our javascript.

The code before webpack, which is working, is used to implement a "famous" fading effect (source gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671)

```
window.requestNextAnimationFrame =
   (function () {
      var originalWebkitRequestAnimationFrame = undefined,
          wrapper = undefined,
          callback = undefined,
          geckoVersion = 0,
          userAgent = navigator.userAgent,
          index = 0,
          self = this;

      // Workaround for Chrome 10 bug where Chrome
      // does not pass the time to the animation function

      if (window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame) {
         // Define the wrapper

         wrapper = function (time) {
           if (time === undefined) {
              time = +new Date();
           }
           self.callback(time);
         };

         // Make the switch

         originalWebkitRequestAnimationFrame = window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;    

         window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame = function (callback, element) {
            self.callback = callback;

            // Browser calls the wrapper and wrapper calls the callback

            originalWebkitRequestAnimationFrame(wrapper, element);
         }
      }

      // Workaround for Gecko 2.0, which has a bug in
      // mozRequestAnimationFrame() that restricts animations
      // to 30-40 fps.

      if (window.mozRequestAnimationFrame) {
         // Check the Gecko version. Gecko is used by browsers
         // other than Firefox. Gecko 2.0 corresponds to
         // Firefox 4.0.

         index = userAgent.indexOf('rv:');

         if (userAgent.indexOf('Gecko') != -1) {
            geckoVersion = userAgent.substr(index + 3, 3);

            if (geckoVersion === '2.0') {
               // Forces the return statement to fall through
               // to the setTimeout() function.

               window.mozRequestAnimationFrame = undefined;
            }
         }
      }

      return window.requestAnimationFrame   ||
         window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
         window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
         window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
         window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||

         function (callback, element) {
            var start,
                finish;


            window.setTimeout( function () {
               start = +new Date();
               callback(start);
               finish = +new Date();

               self.timeout = 1000 / 60 - (finish - start);

            }, self.timeout);
         };
      }
   )
();

// It's then used here in our code here:
loadIcons();
function loadCompanyIcons() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  if (!elements) return;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){    
    var watcher = scrollMonitor.create(el, 2000);
    watcher.enterViewport(function() {      
      var srcToInject = el.getAttribute('data-src');
      var src         = el.getAttribute('src');
      if (src === null && srcToInject!=null) { // do not re-execute for images already with injected src
        el.style.opacity = 0;
        el.style.display = "block";
        el.setAttribute('src',srcToInject);
        el.onload   = imageFound;
        el.onerror  = imageNotFound;        
        function imageFound() {           
          // progressively show image via opacity variation
          (function fade() {
            var val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
            if (!((val += .1) > 1)) {
              el.style.opacity = val;
              requestNextAnimationFrame(fade);
            }
          })();          
        }        
      }
    });
  });  
}
```

It perfectly works when used on a basic js file.

When we tried to move to Webpack and use "exports" we hit a wall. Most Webapck `export` we do have been working so I think this one does not work because it's not a standard:

```
function doSth() {
}
```

But it starts with `window.doSth()...`

Here's what we do today which is failing:

**js/helpers/requestAnimationFramePolyfill.js**

```
export window.requestNextAnimationFrame =
       (function () {
          var originalWebkitRequestAnimationFrame = undefined,
              wrapper = undefined,
              callback = undefined,
              geckoVersion = 0,
              userAgent = navigator.userAgent,
              index = 0,
              self = this;

          // Workaround for Chrome 10 bug where Chrome
          // does not pass the time to the animation function

          if (window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame) {
             // Define the wrapper

             wrapper = function (time) {
               if (time === undefined) {
                  time = +new Date();
               }
               self.callback(time);
             };

             // Make the switch

             originalWebkitRequestAnimationFrame = window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;    

             window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame = function (callback, element) {
                self.callback = callback;

                // Browser calls the wrapper and wrapper calls the callback

                originalWebkitRequestAnimationFrame(wrapper, element);
             }
          }

          // Workaround for Gecko 2.0, which has a bug in
          // mozRequestAnimationFrame() that restricts animations
          // to 30-40 fps.

          if (window.mozRequestAnimationFrame) {
             // Check the Gecko version. Gecko is used by browsers
             // other than Firefox. Gecko 2.0 corresponds to
             // Firefox 4.0.

             index = userAgent.indexOf('rv:');

             if (userAgent.indexOf('Gecko') != -1) {
                geckoVersion = userAgent.substr(index + 3, 3);

                if (geckoVersion === '2.0') {
                   // Forces the return statement to fall through
                   // to the setTimeout() function.

                   window.mozRequestAnimationFrame = undefined;
                }
             }
          }

          return window.requestAnimationFrame   ||
             window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
             window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
             window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
             window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||

             function (callback, element) {
                var start,
                    finish;


                window.setTimeout( function () {
                   start = +new Date();
                   callback(start);
                   finish = +new Date();

                   self.timeout = 1000 / 60 - (finish - start);

                }, self.timeout);
             };
          }
       )
    ();

    // It's then used here in our code here:
    loadIcons();
    function loadIcons() {
      var elements = document.querySelectorAll('img');
      if (!elements) return;
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){    
        var watcher = scrollMonitor.create(el, 2000);
        watcher.enterViewport(function() {      
          var srcToInject = el.getAttribute('data-src');
          var src         = el.getAttribute('src');
          if (src === null && srcToInject!=null) { // do not re-execute for images already with injected src
            el.style.opacity = 0;
            el.style.display = "block";
            el.setAttribute('src',srcToInject);
            el.onload   = imageFound;
            el.onerror  = imageNotFound;        
            function imageFound() {           
              // progressively show image via opacity variation
              (function fade() {
                var val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
                if (!((val += .1) > 1)) {
                  el.style.opacity = val;
                  requestNextAnimationFrame(fade);
                }
              })();          
            }        
          }
        });
      });  
    }
```

then we  do in main.js

```
import {requestNextAnimationFrame} from './helpers/requestAnimationFramePolyfill.js'

loadIcons();
function loadCompanyIcons() {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  if (!elements) return;
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i){    
    var watcher = scrollMonitor.create(el, 2000);
    watcher.enterViewport(function() {      
      var srcToInject = el.getAttribute('data-src');
      var src         = el.getAttribute('src');
      if (src === null && srcToInject!=null) { // do not re-execute for images already with injected src
        el.style.opacity = 0;
        el.style.display = "block";
        el.setAttribute('src',srcToInject);
        el.onload   = imageFound;
        el.onerror  = imageNotFound;        
        function imageFound() {           
          // progressively show image via opacity variation
          (function fade() {
            var val = parseFloat(el.style.opacity);
            if (!((val += .1) > 1)) {
              el.style.opacity = val;
              requestNextAnimationFrame(fade);
            }
          })();          
        }        
      }
    });
  });  
}
```

We also tried:

```
import {window.requestNextAnimationFrame} from './helpers/requestAnimationFramePolyfill.js'
```

but none work and we know this because the icons supposed to use requestAnimationFramePolyfill.js to progressively fade iunto a 1.0 opacity, remain with 0.1 opacity.

I'm not sure though this is the reason. I could not understand it for the past day.

Comment: can you just export `window` and then `import { window } from 'somewhere'`

and calling `window.requestNextAnimationFrame` when you use

Comment: @Natsathorn could you put the specific code in an answer, because I'm totally new to webpakc import/exports. Do you mean I should write export window ?

Comment: also you can do this, `export requestNextAnimationFrame`

Comment: please check my answer @Mathieu

Comment: `window` is the global scope. Adding a function here makes it accessible everywhere. This is essentially the opposite of what web pack is designed to do. Either export the function or add it to the global scope, don't try and do both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to add a function in to `window` object then use it in other place. It's one way to make a function access able by other files, but with ES6 and webpack you can do it other way.

I suggest to not use variable `window` because its may cause some issue with `window` syntax. Also you do not need to add a function to window object anymore.

This should work for you.

**js/helpers/requestAnimationFramePolyfill.js**

```
const requestNextAnimationFrame = (function { your function });
export { requestNextAnimationFrame };
```

**main.js**

```
import { requestNextAnimationFrame } from './helpers/requestAnimationFramePolyfill.js'
```